# Check if Trigger is already running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to run a script on a Google Sheet that updates the sheets after pulling data from a MySQL DB.  It runs a trigger at the end, but I think it's re-starting the trigger every time it runs, resulting in multiple timeBased triggers running concurrently.  I don't know Java, but is there a way to check if the trigger is already running and bypass if it is?

Like:

`if (trigger_running) {continue} else {runTrigger}`?

Here's the basics of the function & trigger:

```
function readData() {
  //open connection
  //fetch data
  //update sheet(s)
  //close connection
}


/* Schedule run/update */
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('readData')
 .timeBased()
 .everyMinutes(5)
 .create();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ScriptApp.newTrigger()` call is in the global space which makes it run *every* time *any* function in your script project gets executed. You should delete that bit of code or comment it out.

Then visit the [My Triggers](https://script.google.com/home/triggers) dashboard and delete the myriad triggers that have been created this far. Finally, open your script project and manually create one trigger to run the `readData()` function. See [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: Aaah, yes, thank you so much.  And that Installable Triggers link was super helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### A trigger test

```
function clockMe(e) {
  if (e) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
    const lr = sh.getLastRow();
    if(lr > 0) {
      sh.getRange(lr + 1,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    } else {
      sh.getRange(1,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    }
  }
}

function createTrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "clockMe").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("clockMe").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
  }
}

function removeTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "clockMe").forEach((t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t)))
}
```

Sheet:

[image]

You can also watch the triggers from here:

[image]